# How can I enable multiple key presses in Turtle?

Tags: python, graphics

I'm trying to ensure that two players on my Turtle pong game are able to move both paddles simultaneously, by continuously pressing the up/down or w/s keys, which control the movement of both paddles. Currently, both players have to press the buttons continuously instead of holding them down - they are not able to hold down keys and move the paddles at the same time.

```
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")
wn.onkeypress(pause_game_button, "p")

if (paddle_a_up, "w") ==1:
(paddle_a_down, "s") ==1:



wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")
wn.onkeypress(pause_game_button, "p")

if (paddle_a_up, "w") ==1:
(paddle_a_down, "s") ==1:
```

Comment: Try adding the listeners to the turtle objects instead of having them in the main function, that worked for me.

Comment: can you post an example?